# Python module not found in Nix-generated Python environment

Tags: python, nix

I need my user environment configured with Python and the `beancount` module available. The way I'm currently doing this is to add this package to `home.packages` (I am using home-manager):

```
(python310.withPackages (_: [ python310Packages.beancount ]))
```

This gives me Python 3.10, but upon trying `import beancount`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

The reason I'm invoking `withPackages` in this way, and not with `(python-packages: with python-packages; [ beancount ])` is because I am overriding the beancount module. I am on an Apple Silicon system and am having issues building beancount on `aarch64-darwin`, so I simply use the `x86_64-darwin` version, which works fine. This is done with the following two overlays:

```
(final: prev: (optionalAttrs (prev.stdenv.system == "aarch64-darwin") {
  pkgs-x86 = import nixpkgs-unstable {
    system = "x86_64-darwin";
      inherit (nixpkgsConfig) config;
    };
}))

(final: prev: (optionalAttrs (prev.stdenv.system == "aarch64-darwin") {
  python310Packages.beancount = final.pkgs-x86.python310Packages.beancount;
}))
```

My suspicion is that the way I'm invoking `withPackages` is the reason the package is not added to Python's environment, but I'm not sure if this is the case. Either way, how would I go about fixing the issue?

I read somewhere that `withPackages` fetches packages from PyPi. Is there a way to force `x86_64-darwin` to be used here? Alternatively, is there a way to manually add modules to Nix's Python environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/languages-frameworks/python.section.md#overriding-python-packages-overriding-python-packages on how to overwrite python packages.

Example overlay from my that I used a while back:

```hs
final: prev: {
  python3 = prev.python3.override {
    packageOverrides = final: prev: {
      python-swiftclient = prev.python-swiftclient.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
        postInstall = ''
          install -Dm644 tools/swift.bash_completion $out/share/bash_completion.d/swift
        '';
      });
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the example as well